# WordPress: show the date of the first post of an author

Tags: wordpress, date, post, author

I'm looking for the PHP code to show **the date of the first post of an author**.

We want to echo the date on the authors page. Ideal would be german date format (e.g. 27.10.2023)

Do you have any ideas?

I found this code:

```
$user_id = 2;
$post = get_most_recent_post_of_user( $user_id );

if ( $post ) {
echo get_the_date( 'Y-m-d', $post );
}
```

but basically i want the opposite.

NOT the most recent post date, but the first post date of the current author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'author' => $user_id,
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
$posts = get_posts($args);

echo get_the_time('Y-m-d', $posts[0]->ID);
```

Comment: That works perfect. The only thing missing in the code above was a comma behind $user_id. But that's the solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: Edited my answer with ",".